# Regex is destroying my UTF- 8 XML (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, xml, utf-8

I have a problem.. I have a code which is downloading some XML files and and deleting some tags I don't need. Since that everything was finde. My XML files was in UTF-8 and I have no problems.

But since I added a code to replace and change the title values my XML files are not longe in UTF-8 and I get this error message:

```
"D:\Anwendung\PHP 7\php-win.exe" C:\Users\Jan\PhpstormProjects\censored\test.php
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE3 0xA4 0x63 0x68 in file:/C:/Users/Jan/PhpstormProjects/censored/data/gamesplanet.xml, line: 1423 in C:\Users\Jan\PhpstormProjects\censored\test.php on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null in C:\Users\Jan\PhpstormProjects\censored\test.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Jan\PhpstormProjects\censored\test.php(86): countAd('data/gamesplane...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Jan\PhpstormProjects\censored\test.php on line 23

Process finished with exit code 255
```

In line 1423 stands: `W㥣hter Von Mittelerde`

And if I don't go through the code below I get no error message and this on in line 1423: `Wächter von Mittelerde`

Does anybody has an idea and can help me?

Code:

```
function loadTitles($tagName, $path){

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->load($path);

    $marker = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

    for ($i = $marker->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $word = $marker->item($i)->textContent;
        $escapedWord = escapWord($word);
        $escapedWord = modifyWord($escapedWord);
        $marker->item($i)->textContent = $escapedWord;
    }

    $dom->saveXML();
    $dom->save($path);
}
function escapWord($string){

    $replaceNothing = [":", ",", ";", "`", "#", "'", "´", "–", "!", "(", ")", ".", "@", "’", "+", "™"];
    $replaceSpace = ["-", "–", "_", "/", ":"];
    $delete = ["Steam", "Eu", "Key", "CD", "Gift", "Edition", "Pack", "Uplay", "Required", "Collection", "Origin", "HD", "Complete", "Digital", "Download", "EA", "Europa", "RPG", "Activated", "Access", "Code", "Limited", "Direct", "Bundle", "Special", "CDKEY", "GLOBAL", "EARLY", "ACCESS", "Card", "Cartel", "Player", "Trade", "DE", "GOG", "Multilanguage", "Multi", "Full", "Only", "UNCUT", "Cut", "Box", "Ps Vita", "VIP", "Rockstar", "Subscription"];

    $string= str_replace($replaceNothing, '', $string);
    $string= str_replace($replaceSpace, ' ', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b~i', '', $string);
    $string= str_replace("&amp;", ' & ', $string);
    $string= strtolower($string);
    $string= ucwords($string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bAsia\b/i', 'ASIA', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\buk\b/i', 'UK', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bAU\b/i', 'AU', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXBOX\b/i', 'XBOX ', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bpc\b/i', 'PC', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bus\b/i', 'US', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bru\b/i', 'RUS', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bRUS\b/i', 'RUS', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPS4\b/i', 'PS4', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bAddon\b/i', 'AddOn', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPlay Station 4\b/i', 'PS4', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPs4\b/i', 'PS4', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPs3\b/i', 'PS3', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPlayStation 4\b/i', 'PS4', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPlay Station 3\b/i', 'PS3', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPlayStation 3\b/i', 'PS3', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPlayStation Network\b/i', 'PSN', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bPSN\b/i', 'PSN', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXX\b/i', 'XX', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXIX\b/i', 'XIX', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXVIII\b/i', 'XVIII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXVII\b/i', 'XVII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXVI\b/i', 'XVI', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXV\b/i', 'XV', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXIV\b/i', 'XIV', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXiii\b/i', 'XIII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXii\b/i', 'XII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bXi\b/i', 'XI', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bIX\b/i', 'IX', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bVIII\b/i', 'VIII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bVII\b/i', 'VII', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bVI\b/i', 'VI', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bV\b/i', 'V', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bIV\b/i', 'IV', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bIII\b/i', 'III', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bII\b/i', 'II', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bdlc\b/i', 'DLC', $string);
    $string= trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string)));

    return $string;
}
function modifyWord($string){

    if(strpos($string, "Counter Strike Offensive") !== false){
        $newstring = explode("Offensive", $string);;
        $newstring[0] = $newstring[0] . "Global Offensive";
        $string = $newstring[0] . $newstring[1];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Greetings and Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you use functions that don't support multibyte characters (`str_replace`, `ucwords`, `strtolower`, `preg_replace` without the u modifier) with a multibyte string (UTF8). Use the `mb_` functions instead and use the u modifier with `preg_replace`.

Comment: Note that `preg_replace` can take an array as first and second parameter.

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet how I can do that? - Because I don't know what u mean by mb_functions and what do you mean with "u modifier"?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php .

Comment: 1) replace `strtolower` to `mb_strtolower`, `ucwords` to `mb_ucwords`, etc 2) add `u` at the end of regexps ("/something/i**u**").

Comment: So, I did it. Is it corret? 

`$string= str_replace($replaceNothing, '', $string);
    $string= str_replace($replaceSpace, ' ', $string);
    $string= preg_replace('~\b(?:' . implode('|', $delete) . ')\b~iu', '', $string);
    $string= str_replace("&amp;", ' & ', $string);
    $string= mb_strtolower($string);
    $string= mb_ucwords($string);
    $string= preg_replace('/\bAsia\b/iu', 'ASIA', $string);
    $string= trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', str_replace("\n", " ", $string)));`

I didn't add u to the trim method. Is that correct?

Comment: PHPStorm is telling me at `mb_ucwords`:
Undefined function mb_ucwords
Decleration of referenced function is not found in built-in library and project file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should activate the unicode mode for your patterns using the `u` modifier. This means you will match unicode characters and codepoint, not single bytes.
The `ä` in `Wächter` consists of several bytes and one of them is interpreted as word end while in single byte mode.

```
preg_match('(.)u', 'äöü', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ä"
}
```

As you can see the example matches the first character, not only the first byte.
Next is the possibility to use arrays as arguments for `preg_replace()`. This allows you to simplify the calls.

```
var_dump(preg_replace(['(ä)u', '(ü)u'], '_', 'äöü'));
```

Output:

```
string(4) "_ö_"
```

But an even better option might be using character classes and the `|` operator in you patterns. `$replaceNothing` and `$replaceSpace` are arrays of characters, they can be changed into character classes:

```
$replaceWithNothing = '([,;`#\'´!().@’+™]+|(?:\b(?:Steam|Eu|Key)\b))u';
$replaceWithSpace = '([-–_/:]+)u';

var_dump(
  preg_replace(
    [$replaceWithNothing, $replaceWithSpace], 
    ['', ' '], 
    'remove (™) and :replace:'
  )
);
```

And for the word replace:

```
$replaceWords = [
  '(\bAsia\b)ui' => 'ASIA';
  '(\buk\b)ui', 'UK'
);
$output = preg_replace(array_keys($words), $words, $input);
```

I am not sure why you don't use a simple replace for the `modifeWord()` function. You're replacing the first occurence of `Counter Strike Offensive"` with `Counter Strike Global Offensive"`.

The comments mention using the mb_* functions. I would suggest using the more modern [ICU grapheme functions](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.intl.grapheme.php). This is the standard, more modern and powerful extension for unicode handling in PHP.

Comment: But this one is not solving my `$string= mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');` problem...

Comment: Kind of, it is better then `strtolower()` will destroy UTF-8, it is an ANSI (single byte) function. So is `ucwords()`. But I don't think you need to transform the string variable - the patterns use the `i` (case insensitive) modifier. Together with `u` this should be enough.

Comment: I only use the strtolower() function because I want to have all strings equal. So I call the strtolower() function and then I want to say ucwords() so they are all appear good

Comment: The mb_*() function are built to provide replacements for the standard string functions that work with multibyte strings. They are part of the default installation and I don't expect that they will be removed in the near future. So you can use them. However I would suggest keeping the ICU functions in mind an learn about them. They are not just Unicode string functions, but internationalization and localization functions.

Comment: Okay thank you! - But my problem is this one and I dont get it solved... it is annoying!

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486578/call-to-undefined-function-mb-internal-encoding-and-mb-strtolower